# Script SFTP with password - HP-UX

Tags: ssh, sftp

I would like create a script in HP-UX to send in sftp with password. I have this command

```
sftp -o PasswordAuthentication=
```

but if I answer yes or no after, I have this issue 
"Host key verification failed"

Comment: however you don't have paassword, but i think password is mandatory in this option.

Comment: try adding `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` if security implications are acceptable...

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding the question, but `PasswordAuthentication` has a *mandatory* argument, you should probably use `sftp -o PasswordAuthentication=yes ...` .

Answer (score 1):

If you have `socat` handy, there's this example in the manual that you could use.

```
   (sleep 5; echo PASSWORD; sleep 5; echo ls; sleep 1) |
   socat - EXEC:'ssh -l user server',pty,setsid,ctty

          EXEC’utes an ssh session to server. Uses a pty for communication
          between socat and ssh, makes it ssh’s controlling tty
          (ctty), and makes this pty the owner of a new process group 
          (setsid), so ssh accepts the password from socat.
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use public/private key authentication, but in case you still want to use the password in your plain text script, I would use `lftp`. It is a great client that allows ftp, sftp, ftps connections, you will only need to use 'here document' for the complete transaction:

```
lftp sftp://your.destination.sftp -u yourUser,YourPassword << fin
    get yourfile
    bye
fin
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try below sftp script with using username,password and destip.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sftp username@destip
expect "username@destip's password:"
send "passwd\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "get filename\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you use passwordless authentication if you're using SFTP on a script. It is possible, I use it when SFTPing between IBM AIX boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Sftp can work without password using

```
pubkey auth = very safe strong encryption
kerberos = need server,encryption is not strong
```

Otherwise use expect to send password,WARNING!
The pass is visible using ps so this solution
is totally unsafe.